# Hide <span> image in a gridview when Eval a Javascript function return is false

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a  inside a Column of gridview. This  is an image. 
I want to hide this image (display:none) when evaluating a javascript function that return true or false (if a file exists on the filesystem of the client)
How can i make it please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: JavaScript won't be able to access the clients file system at all, what is your over all goal?

Comment: I have an activx that can evaluate if a file exists on the client. My goal is : when i create my grid I show or hide a browse image if a file exists

Comment: The page is in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear where you are trying to set the display attribute. Is it in code behind or in a javascript function ?

Assuming that it's a javascript function and you have the Id of the span tag that you want to affect then use something similar to the following...

```
var element = document.getElementById('mySpanId');

if (fileFound == false)
    element.style.display = 'none';
```

Where fileFound is a boolean return value from your js file detector function.

If you don't have the Id (or if you're using code behind) then you will need to post a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make something like that:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="100">
<ItemTemplate>
   <div>
        <span class="glyphicon big-glyphicon glyphicon-open" 
           <%#Eval("MyJavaScripFunctionReturnIFFalse_DisplayNone") >
        </span>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```